# Aggregate column as an array ordered by another column

Tags: sql, presto

Suppose I have the following table

```
select * from (
  values ('A', 1, 7), ('A', 2, 4), ('A', 3, 3),
         ('B', 4, 6), ('B', 5, 5), ('A', 6, 2),
         ('C', 7, 9), ('C', 8, 8)
) example_table("id", "time", "value")
```

I want to aggregate `value` into an `array` grouped by `id`, but the array should be in `time` order.

Desired output:

```
select * from (
  values ('A', array [2, 3, 4, 7]),
         ('B', array [5, 6]),
         ('C', array [8, 9])
) agg_table("id", "arr")
```

`array_sort` only allows us to sort by `value`.

I think the approach will involve `zip` or `zip_with`, but I'm stuck with how to proceed.

---

I think in the latest Presto release I should be able to leverage `array_sort`'s second argument to build a way to sort the `ROW` arrays, but on my version (0.193) this is not available:

https://prestodb.io/docs/0.193/functions/array.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_agg(value ORDER BY time [ ASC | DESC ])`, like in the example below.

Unfortunately, I don't know whether this option was available in 0.193. At least, this answer will hopefully be helpful for others.

```
presto:tiny> with example_table as (
          ->     select * from (
          ->         values ('A', 1, 7), ('A', 2, 4), ('A', 3, 3),
          ->              ('B', 4, 6), ('B', 5, 5), ('A', 6, 2),
          ->              ('C', 7, 9), ('C', 8, 8)
          ->         ) example_table("id", "time", "value")
          -> )
          -> select array_agg(value order by time)
          -> from example_table
          -> group by id
          -> ;
    _col0
--------------
 [6, 5]
 [7, 4, 3, 2]
 [9, 8]
(3 rows)
```